# Sum of matrices using np.add()

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list of n matrices where n = 5:

```
[matrix([[3.62425112, 0.00953506],
        [0.00953506, 1.05054417]]), matrix([[4.15808905e+00, 9.27845937e-04],
        [9.27845937e-04, 9.88509628e-01]]), matrix([[3.90560856, 0.0504297 ],
        [0.0504297 , 0.92587046]]), matrix([[ 3.87347073, -0.12430547],
        [-0.12430547,  1.09071475]]), matrix([[ 3.87697392, -0.00475038],
        [-0.00475038,  1.01439917]])]
```

I want to do element-wise addition of these matrices:

I am trying this:

```
np.add(S_list[0], S_list[1], S_list[2], S_list[3], S_list[4])
```

It works but I don't want to fix `n = 5`

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html), `np.add` should add only two matrices.

However `np.add.reduce(S_list)` or just `sum(S_list)` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Python's built-in function `sum`

```
sum(S_list)
```

Output:

```
[[19.43839338 -0.06816324]
 [-0.06816324  5.07003818]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `np.add(S_list[0], S_list[1], S_list[2], S_list[3], S_list[4])` works ? Because `np.add()` takes as input arguments two arrays . Anyway , the following code does the work if you want to use `np.add()`:

```
sum = np.add(S_list[0],S_list[1])

for i in range(len(S_list) - 2):
    sum = np.add(sum,S_list[i+2])

print(sum)
```